# `--env-file` option for `docker compose` doesn't seem to be working on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I just can't seem to import environment variables using `--env-file`. I followed [docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with---env-file) to provide env file through command line.

I have the following compose file `compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu
    command: printenv
    environment:
      - my_var1=val1
```

And a `.env` file containing environment variables in the same directory:

```
my_var2=val2
```

But the following statement doesn't print the env vars defined within `.env` file:

```
docker compose --env-file .env up
```

It only prints `my_var1=val1` alongside `PATH`, `HOSTNAME`, and `HOME`.

Meanwhile, if I have `env_file: .env` set in compose file, `my_var2=val2` also gets printed.

I have tried on PowerShell, Cmd, and GitBash but in all of them I get the same result.

So what could be wrong? Could it be a bug?

My stack details:

- Docker Compose version v2.10.2
- Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
- PSVersion 5.1.19041.2673
- GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
- Microsoft Windows 22H2

Comment: `services:environment` is for setting up the container. `.env` and `env_file` etc is for variable substitution within the compose file itself. For example `image: ubuntu:${TAG}`

Comment: I read the doc once again more deeply and got the point. Yes, I can see the env vars provided through `--env-file` are accessible within compose file. Now I'm wondering if there's any way to provide a single variable through CLI to be substituted inside compose file. Like `env_file_path` and have `env_file: ${env_file_path}` inside my compose.